# wpf background thread updating UI control

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a working app that adds new a new RibbonTab and a new child control to the Grid.

I would like to put this action onto a background thread as the child control can take a while to gather data from a database, etc.

I have the following code so far:

```
Ribbon Ribbon_Main = new Ribbon();
Grid Grid_Main = new Grid();

Thread newthread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { Graphing_Template.add_report(); }));
newthread2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);  //Is this required?
newthread2.Start();


Class Graphing_Template()
{
  static void add_report()
   {
     RibbonTab rt1 = new RibbonTab();
     MainWindow.Ribbon_Main.Items.Add(rt1);
     // Create control with information from Database, etc.
     // add control to MainWindow.Grid_Main
   }
}
```

I would like the new report control to be created in the background and then added to the Main UI when it is ready.

The solution I went with is:

```
     BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
            {
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
               ---- Fill DataTable with
                args.Result = datagrid_adventureworks_DT();
            };

 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
            {
                DataTable dt1 = (DataTable)args.Result;
                Datagrid_Main.ItemsSource = dt1.AsDataView();
            };
```

Comment: As a general rule, don't touch UI objects unless you're on the UI thread. Do the grunt work in a background thread, sure, but then marshal the UI updates to the UI thread via the dispatcher.

Comment: Could I generate the two child objects and then pass them back to the UI thread?

Comment: I don't know enough WPF to give a definitive answer, sorry. I suspect it would work, but I *know* it wouldn't with winforms, for example, because Win32 UI objects must be touched only by the thread that creates them (WPF doesn't use Win32 UI objects for simple things like buttons, etc.).

Comment: @user3329538 What do you need to do this in the first place? You are just creating an instance of an object. There's no need to put these two on a different thread. In fact, creating a new thread might actually take longer than just creating a `Ribbon` and a `Grid` object on the caller thread.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I have a reporting application that adds different reports. I would like to have the additions on a background thread because it can take a couple of seconds to get database information, etc.

Comment: Well that part is not included in your code nor it's mentioned in the description. You should delegate the part that generates reports on a different thread and then invoke the UI thread when you're ready to add the data to UI. Also, I suggest you use the `Task` class and let .NET take care of spawning/killing worker threads.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I'll look into the `Task` class, thank you.

Comment: If your posted code is representative of what you'll be doing (some side work and a quick update to the UI), I'd recommend taking a look at [the `BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It fires off a thread with an in-built mechanism to communicate with the original thread.  If you're doing anything more complex, though, `Task` is going to be a better choice.

Comment: This is quite useful as well. http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/

Comment: Are you using EF to get your data, and are any of your EF collections bound directly to the UI? OBVIOUSLY if MS have provided us with async EF, and made it easy to bind EF collections to the UI, it must work. not. You may have to use BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyCollection, _myLockObject);

Comment: With detailed Stopwatch testing I found that the main delay was loading the 3rd party charting API for the first time... So I access the object from the API on a background thread when the app first loads and this saves time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test4();

    }
    private void Test1()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            this.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //locks up app
        }
    }
    private void Test2()
    {
        var thd = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            while (true)
            {
                this.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //exception
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }            
        });
        thd.Start();
    }

    private void Test3()
    {   //do the work on the background thread
        var thd = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {   //use dispatcher to manipulate the UI
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() 
                    => { this.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
                }));

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

                //there's nothing to ever stop this thread!
            }
        });
        thd.Start();
    }

    private async void Test4()
    {   //if you are using .Net 4.5 you can use the Async keyword
        //I _think_ any computation in your async method runs on the UI thread, 
        //so don't use this for ray tracing, 
        //but for DB or network access your workstation can get on with 
        //other (UI) work whilst it's waiting
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); });
            this.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to do some further testing on Test3... as I am running into some issues. Will clarify later.